# Serialization problem using protobuf between python and nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, protocol-buffers

I got a compatible problem when serialize a protobuf message between python and nodejs. I have a protobuf message like the one below:

```
message User {
  reserved 2,3;
  string user_id = 1;
  int32 coin = 4;
  int32 exp = 5;
  int32 gem = 6;
  int32 level = 7;
}
```

i would like to serialize a message instance like:

```
"userId": "3562957934"
"coin": 350
"exp": 1
"gem": 30
"level": 1
```

when I do user_pb2.User.SerializeToString()
`\x0a\x0a\x33\x35\x36\x32\x39\x35\x37\x39\x33\x34\x20\xde\x02\x28\x01\x30\x1e\x38\x01`

or in binary

`1101 1110 0000 0010 0010 1000 0000 0001 0011 0000 0001 1110 0011 1000 0000 0001`

---

when I try to deserialize this message in nodejs, I get

```
"userId": "3562957934"
"coin": 381
"exp": 1
"gem": 30
"level": 1
```

which has a wrong "coin" value

then I try to create a message instance (with coin value = 350) and deserialize it in nodejs. I get a different binary:
`\x5c\x0a\x5c\x0a\x33\x35\x36\x32\x39\x35\x37\x39\x33\x34\x20\xc3\x9e\x02\x28\x01\x30\x1e\x38\x01`

or in binary:

`1100 0011 1001 1110 0000 0010 0010 1000 0000 0001 0011 0000 0001 1110 0011 1000 0000 0001`

I found that beside the strange bytes of the head `\x0a\x0a` and `\x5c\x0a\x5c\x0a` the main different between the python and nodejs serialization is the byte `1101 1110` (python) vs `1100 0011 1001 1110` (nodejs), or in string form `3562957934 �(08` (python) vs `3562957934 Þ(08` (nodejs)

my protoc are:
`/usr/local/bin/protoc -I=protos user.proto --python_out=pb`(python)
`/usr/local/bin/protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:protos user.proto -I=protos`(nodejs)

I suppose that given a same message, serialization of python and nodejs should be the same, didn't it?
I tried searching for google official protobuf documents, still cannot found a solution. Does anyone have come across a same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have some sort of UTF-8 encoding problem when passing around the serialized blobs.  The original serialized bytes (from Python) have a byte `0xDE` in them, but the node.js version you quote has `0xC3 0x9E` instead, which is the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode code point U+00DE.

I suggest you use an ASCII-safe encoding such as base64 to pass around the blobs for debugging purposes, just to be on the safe side.  Once that works, you can make sure that you open all the relevant files and streams in binary mode.

Comment: that's right! that was the problem. I have tried base64 encode on python side and decode it on nodejs, message parsed correctly. This problem have bothering me for 2-3 days. Thank you for you answer