# exchanging messages between server(node.js) and client(python/node.js) via protobuf

Tags: python, node.js, protocol-buffers

I'm studying protobuf protocol and got the problem when server(node js) + client(python) do not want to exchange msgs. Between server(node js) + client(node js) no problem. Both clients use the same server. I found difference between python and node js clients, after serialization msg byte arrays are different and it can be a cause of issue. But my knowledge is not enough to fix the issue. May be someone see the problem?

client js

```
const instance = new Product.Id().setValue(12345);
let message = instance.serializeBinary();
console.log(message); //Uint8Array(3) [ 8, 185, 96 ]
let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3008/api/getById', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: message,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/protobuf'}
});
```

client py

```
instance.id.value = 12345
byte = instance.SerializeToString()
print(byte) #b'\n\x03\x08\xb9`'
response = requests.post(url = "http://localhost:3008/api/getById", headers={'Content-Type': 'application/protobuf'}, data=byte)
```

server receives:
client js: 08 b9 60
client py: 0a 03 08 b9 60

Also i found this topic: [Serialization problem using protobuf between python and nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604871/serialization-problem-using-protobuf-between-python-and-nodejs) If it is encoding issue how to encode properly?

Answer (score 0):

Problem detected, instead of:

```
instance.id.value = 12345
byte = instance.SerializeToString()
```

should be:

```
instance.id.value = 12345
byte = instance.id.SerializeToString()
```